# Mean of an element in list of lists

Tags: r, list, vector, mean

I have a list of lists, where each list contains tickers (names) and their values. These tickers stay the same for each list but the values differ. Now, I want to see what is the average value of each of these tickers. The issue is that I don't know how to specify to look into a specific ticker in each list and extract the value. For instance, I want the mean value of "jpm" within this 3 lists. It would be `mean(c(0.08620690,0.10000000,0.10000000))` =
0.095402. How can I do so?

What I have so far:

```r
dput(degree.l)
list(c(schwab = 0, pnc = 0.0344827586206897, jpm = 0.0862068965517241, 
amex = 0.0862068965517241, gs = 0.103448275862069, ms = 0.103448275862069, 
bofa = 0.103448275862069, citi = 0.103448275862069, wf = 0.120689655172414, 
spgl = 0.120689655172414, brk = 0.137931034482759), c(schwab = 0.0166666666666667, 
pnc = 0.05, ms = 0.0666666666666667, spgl = 0.0833333333333333, 
jpm = 0.1, bofa = 0.1, wf = 0.1, amex = 0.1, gs = 0.116666666666667, 
brk = 0.116666666666667, citi = 0.15), c(schwab = 0.0428571428571429, 
gs = 0.0714285714285714, pnc = 0.0714285714285714, citi = 0.0857142857142857, 
amex = 0.0857142857142857, spgl = 0.0857142857142857, jpm = 0.1, 
brk = 0.1, ms = 0.114285714285714, wf = 0.114285714285714, bofa = 0.128571428571429
))

degree.unl <- unlist(degree.l)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` with `stack` in `base R`

```
aggregate(values ~ ind, do.call(rbind, lapply(degree.l, stack)), FUN = mean)
```

-ouptut

```
  ind     values
1  schwab 0.01984127
2     pnc 0.05197044
3     jpm 0.09540230
4    amex 0.09064039
5      gs 0.09718117
6      ms 0.09480022
7    bofa 0.11067323
8    citi 0.11305419
9      wf 0.11165846
10   spgl 0.09657909
11    brk 0.11819923
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` (assuming no NAs) to do elementwise addition (`+`) and divide by the `length` of the `list`

```
 Reduce(`+`, degree.l)/length(degree.l)
    schwab        pnc        jpm       amex         gs         ms       bofa       citi         wf       spgl        brk 
0.01984127 0.05197044 0.07476738 0.08508484 0.09638752 0.09638752 0.10114943 0.10114943 0.11721401 0.11721401 0.13883415
```

---

Or as the OP `unlist`ed the dataset, then using that object, group by the `names` and use `tapply`

```
tapply(degree.unl, names(degree.unl), FUN = mean)
      amex       bofa        brk       citi         gs        jpm         ms        pnc     schwab       spgl         wf 
0.09064039 0.11067323 0.11819923 0.11305419 0.09718117 0.09540230 0.09480022 0.05197044 0.01984127 0.09657909 0.11165846
```

Comment: The first and last one work, and the last one is actually great! The second one though doesn't have the same values to others. That's because the place of tickers is not fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @statwoman the second solution have two assumptions to meet 1) no missing (`NA`) values, 2) length is same for each element and in the same order

Answer (score 4):

Before `unlist`ing,

```r
apply(do.call(rbind, degree.l), 2, mean)
#     schwab        pnc        jpm       amex         gs         ms       bofa 
# 0.01984127 0.05197044 0.07476738 0.08508484 0.09638752 0.09638752 0.10114943 
#       citi         wf       spgl        brk 
# 0.10114943 0.11721401 0.11721401 0.13883415
```

**Edit**: since you say you can't assume that tickers are in order, we can fix that:

```r
nms <- unique(unlist(lapply(degree.l, names)))
nms
#  [1] "schwab" "pnc"    "jpm"    "amex"   "gs"     "ms"     "bofa"   "citi"  
#  [9] "wf"     "spgl"   "brk"   

apply(do.call(rbind, lapply(degree.l, `[`, nms)), 2, mean)
#     schwab        pnc        jpm       amex         gs         ms       bofa 
# 0.01984127 0.05197044 0.09540230 0.09064039 0.09718117 0.09480022 0.11067323 
#       citi         wf       spgl        brk 
# 0.11305419 0.11165846 0.09657909 0.11819923
```

For fun, we can jumble them to confirm this works:

```r
set.seed(42)
degree.l.jumbled <- lapply(degree.l, sample)
degree.l.jumbled
# [[1]]
#     schwab         gs        brk         wf        pnc       amex       bofa 
# 0.00000000 0.10344828 0.13793103 0.12068966 0.03448276 0.08620690 0.10344828 
#       spgl       citi         ms        jpm 
# 0.12068966 0.10344828 0.10344828 0.08620690 
# [[2]]
#       amex         wf       spgl     schwab        jpm       bofa         gs 
# 0.10000000 0.10000000 0.08333333 0.01666667 0.10000000 0.10000000 0.11666667 
#        pnc        brk       citi         ms 
# 0.05000000 0.11666667 0.15000000 0.06666667 
# [[3]]
#         ms       bofa       citi       amex        jpm        brk       spgl 
# 0.11428571 0.12857143 0.08571429 0.08571429 0.10000000 0.10000000 0.08571429 
#         wf         gs        pnc     schwab 
# 0.11428571 0.07142857 0.07142857 0.04285714 
apply(do.call(rbind, lapply(degree.l.jumbled, `[`, nms)), 2, mean)
#     schwab        pnc        jpm       amex         gs         ms       bofa 
# 0.01984127 0.05197044 0.09540230 0.09064039 0.09718117 0.09480022 0.11067323 
#       citi         wf       spgl        brk 
# 0.11305419 0.11165846 0.09657909 0.11819923
```

Comment: So this is not correct, since for instance "jpm" ticker is not always in the same place. But I can actually put them in the same order so it would work. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed, see my edit. To be fair, your comment here is contrarian to your question where you state *"These tickers stay the same for each list"*. Either they stay the same or they don't, you need to be clear in the question, clear with sample data, and be consistent in assessing the results.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```r
get_ticker <- function(t) mean(sapply(d, "[[", t))
sapply(names(degree.l[[1]]), get_ticker)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `rbindlist` + `colMeans`

```
> colMeans(rbindlist(Map(function(x) data.frame(t(x)), degree.1), use.names = TRUE))
    schwab        pnc        jpm       amex         gs         ms       bofa
0.01984127 0.05197044 0.09540230 0.09064039 0.09718117 0.09480022 0.11067323
      citi         wf       spgl        brk
0.11305419 0.11165846 0.09657909 0.11819923
```

Then, if you want to retrieve the mean by any name, e.g., `schwab`, you can try it like below

```
colMeans(rbindlist(Map(function(x) data.frame(t(x)), degree.1), use.names = TRUE))["schwab"]
```